# Is there a way to make Mixamo animation run slow motion?

Tags: animation, mixamo

I downloaded an animation from Mixamo and I wanted to make this animation run really slow, like a slow motion video animation. I basically want to make the character run normally than at a certain point(at frame 100 for example) I want suddenly go slow motion but with the character animation only.

Answer (score 4):

in the timeline, just place your cursor where the slowmo should start, select all keyframes after it, then press S and enjoy slowmo:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can push down the desired action from the *Dope Sheet* (in *Action Editor* mode) into the *Nonlinear Animation* editor:

[image]

Then in the *Nonlinear Animation* editor, select the strip and in the *N panel > Strip > Action Clip*, repeat the action as much as you want, duplicate the strip with an <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and slow down the second strip with the *Playback Scale* value:

[image]

With this solution, you'll go from a speed to another. If necessary, you can gradually slow down or accelerate the action with the *Animated Strip Time* option.